# Utilizo Activities ou Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-activity

Estou com um projeto para desenvolver um app de guia para jogos que mostrará imagens através de um servidor e os guia serão arquivos pdfs baixados e abertos pelo app.

O fluxo seria:

Lista dos consoles (Listview) -> Lista de jogos (GridView) -> Tela onde mostra o guia do jogo.

Porém a quantidade de jogos e guias é grande, queria saber se seria possível apenas Activities e apenas enviar informações para entre elas para aparecer os dados conforme a seleção do usuário.

Independente da resposta, por favor, detalhe a resposta, se possível com exemplo.

Outra dúvida qual seria o melhor servidor para armazenar as imagens e arquivos pdfs?

Obrigado.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

O correto foi utilizar activities porém com recyclerview em vez de Gridview.

O projeto deu tudo certo.